# How does Vorinclex's second ability work at the time of his death?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The Green New Phyrexian Praetor [Vorinclex, Voice of Hunger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vorinclex%2C%20Voice%20of%20Hunger) is quite the beast, his second ability reads:

> If an opponent taps a land for mana, it does not untap during his next untap step.

Say my opponent taps his land for mana, and sometime during his current turn or my next turn, Vorinclex dies somehow. Do his lands remain tapped for the extra turn as originally stated, since they were tapped during the time Vorinclex still lived, or does the effect end immrdiately upon his death, allowing my opponent to untap them as usual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will not untap as usual in the next untap step.

The reason is that after the ability triggered (while Vorinclex was alive) it went on the stack as a replacement effect for the next untap step.

When Vorinclex died, it didn't undo that effect.

Any lands tapped after Vorinclex died would untap in the next untap step.

If Vorinclex instead said something like "While Vorinclex is in play lands do not untap as usual" then it's death would change the situation.

Comment: Or indeed if Vorinclex said just "Lands do not untap as usual", right?  A permanent's continuous effect stops working once that permanent leaves the battlefield; it's just that their triggered effects don't retroactively get erased once they leave play - just as the effect of an activated ability (e.g. "tap [this] to give target creature -2/-2 until end of turn") doesn't get reversed when the creature with that ability leaves play.

Comment: @thesunneversets Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: thats what i thought, thanks Stephen, you tend to answer most of my magic questions lol. (actually most of my questions are confirmations to challenges I receive in-game, the majority of the time I'm right but magic is so darn complicated at times I like to make sure)

Comment: @Ender Actual game play is the best source of good questions, IMHO